# Is there possibility to apply synonyms to fq (filter query) in solr?

Tags: solr

I am thinking to use just fq parameters to retrieve the results (so will not use q); the one issue is that I do not know how to apply my synonyms to fq parameter (if it is possible) - for instance if I have fq:field1:(c++)

Or is there way to preserve c++ (because ++ are stripped away)?

I have tried "c++" (quotes around) also escaping c\+\+
But ++ are stripped away

Comment: This will depend on how your field (`field1`) is processed, as long as you escape the query syntax properly.

Comment: Thank you. Could you suggest how field1 should be processed?

Comment: Start by posting the current analysis chain for the field. If you want to preserve `+`, you'll have to use a tokenizer that does not tokenize on that field, such as the whitespace tokenizer (which only splits on ` `).